FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/mlsample/model/clf.joblib'
I'm trying now to build my docker image
I have my app.py:
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
from joblib import load

MODEL_DIR = os.environ["MODEL_DIR"]
MODEL_FILE = os.environ["MODEL_FILE"]
METADATA_FILE = os.environ["METADATA_FILE"]
MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, MODEL_FILE)
METADATA_PATH = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, METADATA_FILE)

app = Flask(__name__)

#Loading model
clf = load(MODEL_PATH)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    result = ''
    text = ''
    #print(clf.predict(["I am angry"]))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form.get("textTocompute")
        result = clf.predict([text])
    return render_template("index.html", result=result, text=text)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

the requirements.txt:
flask
joblib
numpy
pandas
matplotlib
scikit-learn
and the Dockerfile :
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir ./mlsample

RUN mkdir ./mlsample/model

ENV MODEL_DIR=app/mlsample/model

ENV MODEL_FILE=clf.joblib

ENV METADATA_FILE=metadata.json

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY reviewDataCleaned.csv .

COPY docker-ml.py .

RUN python ./docker-ml.py

COPY app.py .

COPY templates ./templates

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

I want to build this but I got this error:
=> ERROR [ 9/11] RUN python ./docker-ml.py                                                                       32.8s
[ 9/11] RUN python ./docker-ml.py:                                                                                   
32.42 Loading reviewDataCleaned dataset...                                                                              
32.42 fitting model                                                                                                     
32.42 Serializing model to app/mlsample/model/clf.joblib                                                                
32.42 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                
32.42   File "./docker-ml.py", line 54, in <module>
32.42     dump(clf,MODEL_PATH)
32.42   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 481, in dump
32.42     with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
32.42 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/mlsample/model/clf.joblib'


Dockerfile:25
  23 |     COPY docker-ml.py .
  24 |     
  25 | >>> RUN python ./docker-ml.py
  26 |     
  27 |     COPY app.py .
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python ./docker-ml.py" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

How can I fix it?

This is the actual error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/mlsample/model/clf.joblib'

The Docker container could not find the file app/mlsample/model/clf.joblib. I'm assuming the script itself is supposed to create  the file, therefore I'm inclined to think that the issue resides in this line from the Dockerfile:
ENV MODEL_DIR=app/mlsample/model

You're setting MODEL_DIR to a relative path. The result ends up being the Docker WORKDIR + MODEL_DIR, so /app/app/mlsample/model. Try setting MODEL_DIR to the correct relative path, or to an absolute path, i.e.:
# Absolute path
ENV MODEL_DIR=/app/mlsample/model

# Or path relative to the WORKDIR
ENV MODEL_DIR=mlsample/model


Yes it was that, I added the / and it works Thanks
